# Validar tamanho de input com AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Tenho um campo em um formulario que necessito validar com angular. O campo dever ter até 11 caracteres. Caso tenha menos que 5 deve ser exibdo uma mensagem de erro exigindo do usuário uma numeração correta.

**Controlador Angular**

```
angular.module('xxx') .controller('yyyController', function ($scope) {
    var vm = $scope;      
    vm.validarCPF = function(){

      if( condicao < 11){
       //mensagem de erro
      }

    };
```

**Código HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" ng-model="cpfusuario">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as diretivas `ng-minlength` e `ng-maxlength` direto no HTML como abaixo:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="meuForm">
    <label>
       User name:
       <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" ng-model="cpfusuario" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="11" maxlength="11">
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="meuForm.cpf.$error.minlength">
        Tamanho mínimo de 5!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="meuForm.cpf.$error.maxlength">
        Tamanho máximo de 11!</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Veja mais na documentação do AngularJS:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Comment: MAs quanto a mensagem de erro ? Como solicitar ao usuario uma numeracao correta ?

Comment: E como validar isso no controlador ?? Não quero deixar o html cheio de ng-s...

Comment: Tenho de fazer a validação no controler...

Comment: A idéia de se usar o AngularJs é exatamente a de diminuir o código javascript. quanto à mensagem, esse '<div role="alert">' é responsável por exibir a mensagem ao usuário. Lembrando que essa utilização das diretivas e código HTML ao invés de encher nosso javascript é um dos diferenciais do AngularJS e da utilização de HTML5.